# How import different datsets in RShiny using radioButtons()?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create RShiny dashboard, which will show different data based on which condition is selected in  `radioButtons()` . Generally, if one of the condition is selected then different data is imported to the dashboard. However I have an error "Can't access reactive value 'dist' outside of reactive consumer." It seems that something reactive should be used with `input$dist`. The only difference in the code are the following lines

```
real_time_data_subset <- reactive(subset(real_time_data(), date == input$select_date ))
real_time_data_subset <- reactive(subset(historical_time_data()))
```

Could you help, how can I create different tables (because of different data imports) using  `radioButtons()`
or alternatives?

```
library(rshiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
 
 # Application title
 titlePanel("test"),
 
 # Sidebar with slider input to select date range
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     
     
     radioButtons("dist", "Data:",
                  c("The most recent" = "most_recent",
                    "Historical" = "historical"), selected = "most_recent"),
     dateInput("select_date", "Date:", value = Sys.Date() #max(as.Date(entsoe_syspower_data$time))
     )
     
   ),
   
   # plot graphs
   mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
     
     tabPanel("Up", 
              h3(helpText("Quantity")),
              tableOutput("table_up")),
     tabPanel("Down", 
              h3(helpText("Quantity")),
              tableOutput("table_down")),
     
     
     tabPanel("Weekly PnL",
              h3(helpText("week year")),
              tableOutput("table_week")),
     tabPanel("Monthly PnL",
              h3(helpText("month year")),
              tableOutput("table_month"))
   )
   )
 ))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
 if (input$dist == "most_recent"){
   
   ####################################### DATA DOWNLOAD ####################################### 
 real_time_data <- reactive({real_time_function_data_aggregation()})
 real_time_data_subset <- reactive(subset(real_time_data(), date == input$select_date ))

 
 week_data <- get_pnl_data(type = "week")
 month_data <- get_pnl_data(type = "month")

 
 
 ####################################### Create tables ####################################### 
 
 plot_up() <- real_time_data_subset()[c("time_character","Up")]
 plot_down() <- real_time_data_subset()[c("time_character","Down")]
 
 output$table_up <-  renderTable(plot_up())
 output$table_down <-  renderTable(plot_down())
 
 output$table_week <-  renderTable(week_data, digits = 0)
 output$table_month <-  renderTable(month_data, digits = 0)
   
 }else{
   
   ####################################### DATA DOWNLOAD ####################################### 
   real_time_data <- reactive({real_time_function_data_aggregation()})
   real_time_data_subset <- reactive(subset(historical_time_data()))
   
   
   week_data <- get_pnl_data(type = "week")
   month_data <- get_pnl_data(type = "month")
   
   
   
   ####################################### Create tables ####################################### 
   
   plot_up() <- real_time_data_subset()[c("time_character","Up")]
   plot_down() <- real_time_data_subset()[c("time_character","Down")]
   
   output$table_up <-  renderTable(plot_up())
   output$table_down <-  renderTable(plot_down())
   
   output$table_week <-  renderTable(week_data, digits = 0)
   output$table_month <-  renderTable(month_data, digits = 0)
 }
 

 
 
 

 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a listener that will evaluate your ifelse clause

```
observeEvent(input$dist,{ 
 // put your ifelse logic here
})
```